# Can I resolve one Maven dependency from one repo and another dependency from second repo in same POM?

Tags: maven, repository, dependency-management

We have a project with multiple parent/child POMs. All the POMs are pointing to a single repository for resolving all Maven dependencies.

Now I have a need like: In a single POM, one jar has to be downloaded from repo1 and rest 4-5 jars from repo2.

How can you do that?

Comment: A pom is never pointing to a repository. A pom declares repositories (which is bad practice). You should use a repository manager to handle that. In your poms usually there should not define any repository at all. Only in the settings.xml you should define the repositories or best only a single group which is used to solve the dependencies from which is handled in background by a repository manager like Neuxs.

Comment: @khmarbaise If it's bad practice why does [Settings Reference, Servers](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers) say: "_The repositories for download and deployment are defined_ [sic! not _declared_? ;] _by the `repositories` and `distributionManagement` elements of the POM._"? And, I know, _declaring_ is the official wording for POMs (due to their declarative nature) but why do you think that _pointing to_ is that bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
What I have understand the, 
I can setup maven repo in artifactory/nexus 
e.g. http://localhost:18081/artifactory/ --> L1

1. create remote(R1) repository in artifactory, which can point URL to outside repository, hosted by artifactory/nexus
e.g http://remotehost:18081/artifactory/remote-repo1

2. create a "virtual" repository(V1) in my artifactory and add remote(R1) in to this V1.
3. Let all my poms points to my local artifactory virtual repository(V1), 
e.g.>http://localhost:18081/artifactory/virtual

 that way, maven will look
a. local .m2 folder
b. then look for jars in virtual repo of my artifactory
hence virtual will look
  b1. all local repo
  b2. all remote cache repo
  b3. all remote repo --> e.g.http://remotehost:18081/artifactory/remote-repo1

I am experimenting this,once succeed, i will update
EDIT :
This has worked for me, the only hiccup I faced was my ~/.m2/settings.xml
the snapshot was false, and my jar in remote repo is a snapshot jar.
After changing this value to true, now its fetching the jars :)
 </profile>
                <profile>
                        <id>virtual-repo</id>
                        <repositories>
                                <repository>
                                        <id>central</id>
                                          <url><repo_url></url>
                                        <snapshots>
                                                **<enabled>true</enabled>**
                                        </snapshots>
                                </repository>
                        </repositories>
```

Comment: This has worked for me, the only hiccup I faced was my ~/.m2/settings.xml

Answer (score 2):

In a word - yes. Maven's dependency resolution mechanism is completely separate from the repository mechanism. Theoretically, you could have every single jar delivered from its own repository (however ridiculous it may to actually do this).

Comment: Could you please share the tags ?
Because I am not able to see any tags related to repo url inside <dependency> tag in pom file